# How to wait until post method finished Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am working on Knowledge Testing System, so as an admin I can create tests.
On the page where I create tests, first of all I enter info about test and count of questions.
Then for every question I enter count of answers for this question and info about question.
Then for every answer I enter some info and then I click on submit button.

Order of actions must be as follows:

Post test  -> Post first question -> Post answers for first questions - > Post second question and etc.

So I need to wait until first question created, then create every answer for this question and only then create second question and answers for it.

Order is very important and must be as I wrote.

But I have a mistake, my order is not working as I want because of my post methods work asynchronous.

For example, if I create 2 questions and 2 answers for each questions my order turns in this:

Post Test finished -> Post Question 2 finished - > Post Question 1 finished - > Post all answers finished

So I need to know, how to wait until post method finished.

Here is my method where I post questions and answers for them:

```
for(let item of this.sas){// sas is type Map<Question, Answer[]>
      // get question info
      let q = document.getElementById(`q_${ii+1}`) as HTMLInputElement;
      let t = document.getElementById(`t_${ii+1}`) as HTMLInputElement;
      let isSin = true;
      if(t.checked){
        isSin = false;
      }
      let question = new Question();
      question.Content = q.value;
      question.IsSingle = isSin;
      //

      // get answers for this question
      let answers = [];
      for(let j of item[1]){
        let isCorrect = document.getElementById(`a_isCorrect_${ii}:${j}`) as unknown as HTMLInputElement;
        let content = document.getElementById(`a_content_${ii}:${j}`) as unknown as HTMLInputElement;
        let mark =  document.getElementById(`a_mark_${ii}:${j}`) as unknown as HTMLInputElement;

        let answer = new Answer();
        answer.IsCorrect = isCorrect.checked;
        answer.Content = content.value;
        answer.Mark = Number(mark.value);
        answers.push(answer);
        j++;
      }

      //post question
      this.questionService.createQuestion(question).subscribe(data=> {
        console.log(`question ${question.Content} done`);
      //

         //post answers for question
           from(answers).pipe(
             map(answer => this.answerService.createAnswer(answer).subscribe(data => { 
                          console.log(`answer ${answer} done` ) } ) )
           ).subscribe(s=> { console.log("done")});
      //
      });
      ii++;
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `concatMap` here, it will wait step by step for every emit.

```js
//post question
this.questionService.createQuestion(question).pipe(
    // executes answers only when question emits.
    concatMap(data=> {
        console.log(`question ${question.Content} done`);
        //

        //post answers for question
        return from(answers).pipe(
            concatMap(answer => this.answerService.createAnswer(answer).pipe(
                tap(data => console.log(`answer ${answer} done` ) ),
            )),
            finalize(() => console.log("done")),
        );
    }),
).subscribe();
```

if you want the whole thing:

```js
let ii = 0;
from(this.sas).pipe(
    contactMap(item => {
        // get question info
        let q = document.getElementById(`q_${ii+1}`) as HTMLInputElement;
        let t = document.getElementById(`t_${ii+1}`) as HTMLInputElement;
        let isSin = true;
        if(t.checked){
            isSin = false;
        }
        let question = new Question();
        question.Content = q.value;
        question.IsSingle = isSin;
        //

        // get answers for this question
        let answers = [];
        for(let j of item[1]){
            let isCorrect = document.getElementById(`a_isCorrect_${ii}:${j}`) as unknown as HTMLInputElement;
            let content = document.getElementById(`a_content_${ii}:${j}`) as unknown as HTMLInputElement;
            let mark =  document.getElementById(`a_mark_${ii}:${j}`) as unknown as HTMLInputElement;

            let answer = new Answer();
            answer.IsCorrect = isCorrect.checked;
            answer.Content = content.value;
            answer.Mark = Number(mark.value);
            answers.push(answer);
            j++;
        }
        ii++;

        //post question
        return this.questionService.createQuestion(question).pipe(
            // executes answers only when question emits.
            concatMap(data=> {
                console.log(`question ${question.Content} done`);
                //

                //post answers for question
                return from(answers).pipe(
                    concatMap(answer => this.answerService.createAnswer(answer).pipe(
                        tap(data => console.log(`answer ${answer} done` ) ),
                    )),
                    finalize(() => {
                        console.log("done");
                    ),
                );
            }),
        );
    }),
    finalize(() => {
      // call done function here.
    ),
).subscribe();
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem, my order now is:
Test -> Question 1 - > Question 2 -> Answer 1 -> Answer 3 -> Answer 2 -> Answer 4

Comment: Then simply use concatMap above. I'll update the answer soon.

Comment: Please take a look above.

Comment: Thank you very much, it woks as it must!

Answer (score 1):

I believe your best bet, **AS LONG AS YOU DON'T NEED TO POST A BUNCH**, is probably something recursive like so:

```
function handleQuestion(item, index = 0) {
let q = document.getElementById(`q_${index+1}`) as HTMLInputElement;
let t = document.getElementById(`t_${index+1}`) as HTMLInputElement;
let isSin = true;
if(t.checked){
    isSin = false;
}
let question = new Question();
question.Content = q.value;
question.IsSingle = isSin;

let answers = [];
for(let j of item){
    let isCorrect = document.getElementById(`a_isCorrect_${index}:${j}`) as unknown as HTMLInputElement;
    let content = document.getElementById(`a_content_${index}:${j}`) as unknown as HTMLInputElement;
    let mark =  document.getElementById(`a_mark_${index}:${j}`) as unknown as HTMLInputElement;

    let answer = new Answer();
    answer.IsCorrect = isCorrect.checked;
    answer.Content = content.value;
    answer.Mark = Number(mark.value);
    answers.push(answer);
    j++;
}

this.questionService.createQuestion(question).subscribe(data=> {
    from(answers).pipe(
    map(answer => this.answerService.createAnswer(answer).subscribe(data => { 
        console.log(`answer ${answer} done` ) } ) )
    ).subscribe(s=> {
        index++;
        if (this.sas[index]) {
            handleQuestion(this.sas[index], index);
        }
    });
}); }
```

Comment: But what should I pass in parameters when I call `handleQuestion` for first time?

Comment: And It is not allowed to get elements from type Map by index, so `this.sas[index]` will always return undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You may combine two observables... to reach the response data when both have responded already.

```
fetchData(): Observable<any[]> {
    return combineLatest(
        this.observable1$(),
        this.observable2$()
    );
}
```